# Paint in a selected area

Tags: android, android-animation, android-gesture

I am creating a Android app for kids. The kids will be shown a letter with a arrow showing that how the kid has to practice writing the letter. For now, I know how to paint using the SurfaceView.

Question: The kids should trace the letter. Whenever the kid touches outside the letter it should be ignored and no paint should be applied over there. how to achieve this. Any pointer is highly appreciated

[image]

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?  Getting touch input?  Determining if the touch point is inside the shape?  Drawing?

Comment: yes i need to find if the touch point is inside the drawing